# Save a list of elements inside an image in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing

- Is there anyway to save a list of elements/linked list inside an
  image?
- I need to save information like a relationship between neighborhood pixel values in an image. So i will be using a List<>  containing (pixel value, relative coordinate of next pixel)

  ```
      List<Dictionary<int, int[]>> globalList = new List<Dictionary<int, int[]>>(); 
     // list contains a map for [water mark pixel, {matching cover image pixel, best match value}] for each watermark
  ```
- Please suggest some ways to save it inside my image as a secret information which is hard to remove except methods like :

  - Increasing bit-depth
  - save into image properties as header info
- I know these can be removed easily. I need a non-removable way ( in C#).

Comment: What you probably need is steganography: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29411444/5064986 - you'll need to use lossless jpeg or png (stock Jpeg compression is lossy, so you'll loose your data)

Comment: There are many possibilities to put data information into image. E.g. slightly modifying color for each pixel: if value is `even`, then it's `1`, if `odd`, then it's `0` and form hidden sequence of bits out of this to *sign* image (and to prove plagiarism/copyright later).

Comment: @Daniel :Steganography will change the LSB of pixel.That means the color value of certain pixel is changed !. I can't use that technique in my project as i have to compare pixel values and do some operations later.So this wont be helpful

Comment: @Sinatr , I need the exact value of the pixel. Steganography is also not allowed in my project due to this reason. So u mean by adding a hidden bit pattern where the 1s' nd 0s' are changed and create a map between changed places?

Comment: If you change color by just 1 (to make it odd or even) it will not be noticeable (unless you have 16 colors/pixel). This bit stream can be input into any picture, 256x256 image can hold 1024 bytes of data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was kind of unclear, but I assume you're trying to add a hidden watermark?

The easiest way would probably be to convert your data to a BitArray and then increase the value of each pixel's color by 1 or 0 bits as you iterate through the array.  You would then retrieve your data by comparing the resulting photo to your original.

**Edit**: 
If you want to store the data outside of the header/properties and without modifying colors, then I don't have a solution for you.  As far as I know, those are your only options.  You could always do what I mentioned and then include the watermarked portion of your image as a static BitArray within your application for comparison.

Comment: Actually the idea is for an invisible watermarking project. I have already done the invisible embedding of watermark pixel into my cover image by comparing pixel values of watermark and cover, then by replacing the watermark pixel to cover pixel if the threshold is nearly zero. I cannot fully explain the project as it has so many parts. Here i wanna mention, that i have already changed cover image pixels so to add a list of information into an image still i need to modify pixels? if it so, then i can't make it done. B'coz i need to compare pixels later for watermark extraction.

Comment: How large is the data you're storing?